# How to publish Threshold event of combined connections to Message Bus?

Tags: threshold, solace, message-bus

What's the  topic of connection threshold events? How do I listen to connection count threshold events over the message bus, and how do I figure out what is the current connection count?

Comment: Are you looking for instructions to publish the threshold events over the message bus, or are you trying to query the current connection counts over the message bus?

Comment: Yes,I want to know what  topic of  threshold event that i can subscribe ,and the current connection counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection threshold events can be published over the message bus to the following topics:

`#LOG/WARNING/VPN/<router-name>/VPN_VPN_CONNECTIONS_HIGH/<vpn-name>` when the connection count exceeds the high threshold.

`#LOG/INFO/VPN/<router-name>/VPN_VPN_CONNECTIONS_HIGH_CLEAR/<vpn-name>` when the connection count goes below the clear threshold.

If desired, you can apply wildcards to the topics. For example, `#LOG/*/VPN/<router-name>/VPN_VPN_CONNECTIONS*/<vpn-name>`.

Note that you will need to fill in `<router-name>` and `<vpn-name>` with appropriate values.

---

In order to have the connection count threshold events published over the message bus, you will need to do the following:

a. Configure the VPN to "Publish Message VPN Event Messages".

b. Your application needs to subscribe to the topic for connection threshold events.

---

In order to figure out the current connection count, you will need to send a SEMP over message bus query.

a. Enable SEMP over Message Bus Show Commands on the VPN.

b. Send a SEMP over Message Bus query. There's an SempGetOverMB sample in the API with detailed instructions to do this. You can also refer to the [documentation](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Message_Bus_and_Events_Management/Using_SEMP_to_Manage_and_Monitor_Routers.html#ww321071) for details.

```
<rpc semp-version="soltr/7_2">
<show>
<message-vpn>
<vpn-name>default</vpn-name>
</message-vpn>
</show>
</rpc>
```

c. Parse the XML based response.

```
<rpc-reply semp-version="soltr/7_2">
<rpc>
<show>
<message-vpn>
<vpn>
<name>default</name>
<connections-service-smf>3</connections-service-smf>
<connections-service-web>0</connections-service-web>
<connections-service-rest-incoming>0</connections-service-rest-incoming>
<connections-service-mqtt>0</connections-service-mqtt>
<connections-service-rest-outgoing>0</connections-service-rest-outgoing>
<max-connections>10</max-connections>
<max-connections-service-smf>9000</max-connections-service-smf>
<max-connections-service-web>9000</max-connections-service-web>
<max-connections-service-rest-incoming>9000</max-connections-service-rest-incoming>
<max-connections-service-mqtt>9000</max-connections-service-mqtt>
<max-connections-service-rest-outgoing>6000</max-connections-service-rest-outgoing>

... Removed non-relevant portions for clarity ...

</vpn>
</message-vpn>
</show>
</rpc>
<execute-result code="ok"/>
</rpc-reply>
```

Note that there is a system limit of 10 SEMP poll requests per second, and some topics should not be polled. Refer to the [documentation](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Message_Bus_and_Events_Management/Using_SEMP_to_Manage_and_Monitor_Routers.html#ww343404) for details.